# NSMutableAttributedText setAttributes:range: method is not applying my attributes to it's text

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa, pyobjc

I currently am trying to attributed text in my NSTextField  *that uses the Apple system font (San Francisco)* to show a message. I have tried many methods to instantiate an instance of a `NS(Mutable)AttributedText` that contains 4 lines of words, each are either italicized, bolded, or regular.

Some of these methods include:

- [`initWithHTML:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1525953-initwithhtml?language=objc)
- [`initWithURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1530490-initwithurl?language=objc)
- [`initWithRTF:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1532912-initwithrtf?language=objc)

There are some [others ones](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring?language=objc) but these seemed the most doable. When I do it with HTML it works fine, but I only get the Times New Roman font and cant have it be San Francisco apple's default one, even through any CSS. When I give `initWithRTF:` the plain text output of a .rtf file into a NSData object nothing outputs in the text field. The URL one takes .txt files but not .rtf files so no attributed text here either.

The only other option is do this manually with the [`NSMutableAttributedText`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring?language=objc) class where you specify ranges of letters in a `NSMutableAttributedText` object containing your text (e.g. apply bold to index of letters 0-11 NSMakeRange). Here I am having trouble, I am using [this generator website](https://andresinaka.github.io/Transformer/) to give me Objective-C code for this.

I am using Python with PyObj-C so bare wit me here...

```py
# Create instance of NSMutableAttributedString with my text
attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.alloc().initWithString_(
            f"Word - word\n/phonetic/\ndefinition\ntype\n")

# Create a centered paragraph style to apply centering to text
paragraphStyle0 = NSMutableParagraphStyle.alloc().init()
paragraphStyle0.setAlignment_(1) # 1 is center

# Create set of attributes for our first line
attributes = {
        "NSParagraphStyleAttributeName": paragraphStyle0,
        # Bolded style
        "NSFontAttributeName": NSFont.fontWithName_size_("HelveticaNeue-Bold", 17)
        }
# Apply the attributes to the first line (first 1 letters)
attributedString.setAttributes_range_(attributes, NSMakeRange(0, 11))
self.definitionField.setAttributedStringValue_(attributedString)
```

(Objective-C equivalent)

```objectivec
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"Word - word\n/phonetic/\na word\nnoun\n"];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle0 = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle0.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

NSDictionary <NSAttributedStringKey, id> *attributes0 = @{
   NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:13],
   NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle0
};
[attributedString addAttributes:attributes0 range: NSMakeRange(0, 11)];
```

If I print my `attributedString` object I get this:

```
Word - word{
    NSFontAttributeName = "\"HelveticaNeue-Bold 17.00 pt. P [] (0x1057b75a0) fobj=0x1057b6d30, spc=4.73\"";
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName = "Alignment 2, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0 PresentationIntents (\n) ListIntentOrdinal 0 CodeBlockIntentLanguageHint ''";
}
/phonetic/
definition
type
{
}
```

When I put it into the Rich Text enabled text field I get this (unchanged text nothing happened...)
[image: Text inputted by the test button]

I have no idea why the top line (first 12 letters) aren't bolded, I must being doing something wrong... Any suggestions as to what I may be missing?

Comment: I tried your Objective-C code and it works for me (`NSFont` instead of `UIFont`). `NSTextAlignmentCenter` is `2`, `NSFontAttributeName` is `"NSFont"` and `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` is `"NSParagraphStyle"`.

Comment: Oh thanks! I tried your replacement names for my dictionary of the attribute keys and they work!

Answer (score 0):

The first commenter solved the problem. My keys in my dictionary for the attributes were wrong.

I had to remove the `AttributeName` at the end of my keys and the attributes worked for me!

```py
attributes = {
    "NSParagraphStyleAttributeName": paragraphStyle0,
    "NSFontAttributeName": NSFont.fontWithName_size_("HelveticaNeue-Bold", 17)
}
```

```py
attributes = {
    "NSParagraphStyle": paragraphStyle0,
    "NSFont": NSFont.fontWithName_size_("HelveticaNeue-Bold", 17)
}
```